# Error al abrir proyecto en VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Me pasaron un proyecto en `Visual Studio 2010` para modificar, pero cuando trato de abrirlo me aparecen algunos errores y me es imposible trabajar sobre él. Adjunto dos imágenes con los errores.

¿Alguien tiene idea de lo que podría ser?

Gracias.

[image: error 1]

[image: error 2]

Comment: Puedes aceptar el mensaje primero; para los otros: Fui el program hizo con la misma version de Visual Studio que tu tienes? Parece que algunos Controls (o asemblias, o algo asi) faltan.

Comment: Parece que la versión del proyecto es diferente a la versión del Visual Studio que usted está usando para abrir el proyecto. Hable con la persona que le pasó este proyecto o descargue un versión mas actualizada de Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El dialogo de la izquierda es solo una advertencia puede aceptarlo sin problemas.

El de la derecha te esta indicando que el codigo estaba vinculado a un repositorio de codigo, como ser Team Foundation, o similar, sino tienes acceso al repositorio puede aceptar el dialog desconetandolo temporalmente o sino el segundo option para quitarlo por completo.

La imagen de abajo hace referencia a un tipo de proyecto del cual no tienes el template instalado. No quiere decir que no sea un proyecto en VS2010, seguramente lo sea porque veo el la solucion pudo abrirla.
Deberias ver si puede editar con el notepad el `.csproj` y ver si da una pista de que tipo de proyecto se trata para asi instalar el tipo de template que requiere el VS.
Tambien podrias preguntarte a quien te paso el desarrollo que tipo de proyecto creo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por las respuestas. Al final descubrí que se trata de un proyecto Xamarin (esto el cliente no me lo habia dicho o no lo sabia, todavia no pude hablar con él).

Answer (score 1):

- El primer "error" es solo una advertencia por haber descargado el proyecto de algún otro lada.
- El segundo mensaje se debe probablemente a que te pasaron el código que estaba conectado al TFS y simplemente te menciona que ya no tienes conexión
- El tercero y error verdadero es que la versión de Visual Studio que tienes no admite o no tiene instalado la extensión para abrir el tipo de proyecto que tienes.

Para averiguar que tipo de proyecto es:

- Dale clic derecho al proyecto y Escoje Editar `iDismerco.csproj` proyecto o abre el archivo `.csproj` con un editor de texto.
- Unica la sección `<ProjectTypeGuids>` y toma nota de los GUIDs
- Busca el GUID en internet para averguar que tipo de proyecto es, por ejemplo en esta página: [List of Visual Studio Project Type GUIDs](http://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs)
- Dependiendo del tipo de proyecto es posible que falte instalar alguna extensión para que abra tu proyecto, se requiera una edición mas avanzada de VS o simplemente una versión superior.

Comment: Muchas gracias por las respuestas. Al final descubrí que se trata de un proyecto Xamarin (esto el cliente no me lo habia dicho o no lo sabia, todavia no pude hablar con él).